# QGIS - How to update Python Init Function

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In layer properties I can set a "Python Init Function" and it works perfectly.
But I can't find a way to update it when developing (without closing QGIS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated to QGIS 2.14 and now there more option in layer properties > Fields.
Using "Load from external file", it's now possible to specify an "External File".
I can now modify that file and see my updates automatically.